# Check if each value in the column is a string or numeric

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to figure out whether or not each value in my column is a numerical value or a non-numerical value.

```
df = data.frame(help = c(456, 'superduper'),
                correct_answer = c("numeric","string"))
```

I've tried is.numeric or is.character, on a row-by-row basis but this doesnt seem to work as the entire column is coded as a character.

I know this is a basic question, but any help is appreicated.

Comment: You could check for the possibility of coercing to numeric,  E.g. - `is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$help)))` Why do you have combined numeric and text data in the first place though?

Comment: What is wrong with using `is.numeric(df$help)` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I think the point is that there are numbers and character strings all encoded in a character variable.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought would be to consider if the value can be coerced to a number. E.g.:

```
is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$help)))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

The bonus is that this will work for variations on number formats like `3`, `3.2` or even `3e5`

Comment: clever, i like it

Comment: @runningbirds `suppressWarnings` would be useful in this case

Answer (score 1):

One option here to check for numeric strings would be to replace all digits with empty string and then check if the resulting length be zero:

```
is.help.numeric <- nchar(gsub("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", "", df$help) == 0)
```

If a given entry in `help` has even one non-digit, then its corresponding entry in `is.help.numeric` would be `FALSE`.